# I want to filter exact word that I want in Excel

Tags: excel, filter, ms-word, match, formula

Example

```
ROW1- **Ar**ticle
ROW2- Book "**AR**"
ROW3- Book2 "**AR**I"
```

I want to filter this one only "**AR**"
Help me

Comment: Before posting a question in StackOverflow, it's a good idea to review the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) first. Starting there will help you find ways of asking a question that is more likely to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you have something like this.

[image]

Click on the column header "Words with AR" (Excel assumes the top cell is a header), and then in the top menu, select Data and click the Filter button.

[image]

Then click the drop-down filter button at the top of the column. Make sure only AR is checked and click OK

[image]

And here's the result.

[image]